# Finding restriction of the ultraproduct that behaves like $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: logic, order-theory, model-theory, integers, filters

Let $\mathcal{A}= \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{A}_n /\mathcal{U}$, where $\mathcal{A}_n=(\{0, 1,  \dots, n\},<)$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter of $\mathbb{N}$.

Can we find some $S \subseteq A$ such that $(S,<^\mathcal{A}|_S)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

---

I see that the smallest element of $\mathcal{A}$ is $[0,0, \dots]$, and the greatest is $[0,1,2, \dots]$.

My idea was to take the following approach:

1. Find an explicit scheme for constructing the $A$-successor of an element $\neq [0,0,\dots]$
2. Find an explicit scheme for constructing the $A$-predeccessor of an element $\neq [0,1,2,\dots]$
3. Find an explicit element of $A$ such that, no matter how many times we apply 1 or 2, we never hit $[0,0, \dots]$ or $[0,1,2,\dots]$
4. Let $S$ be the closure of the element from 3 under the operations from 1 and 2, and prove $S$ has the desired properties.

I know that non-prinicpal means the intersection of all sets in $\mathcal{U}$ is just the empty set. I know this is equivalent to saying that there is no $n$ such that $n$ belongs to every $U \in \mathcal{U}$.

I'm still new to ultrafilters so I would like to do this from scratch as much as possible (i.e. without relying on any theorems that I haven't learned yet. I know Los Theorem but that's about it.)

Comment: Given a sequence $\sigma\in\prod \mathcal{A}_n$, let $\sigma^+$ be the sequence given by $$\sigma^+(n)=\min\{n, \sigma(n)+1\}.$$ Can you show that $\sigma^+$ is the successor of $\sigma$ in the ultrapower, as long as $\sigma$ doesn't "grow too quickly"? Similarly, the predecessor of a $\sigma$ which doesn't "grow too slowly" will be given by $\sigma^-(n)=\max\{0,\sigma(n)-1\}$. Then you'll just need to find a single sequence which grows at a "medium" rate, to be the $0$ of your desired copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ (something like $$(\lfloor{n\over 2}\rfloor)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$ will do the job nicely).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for this. I will try to work out the details. One thing I'm a little stuck on is how to take advantage of $\mathcal{U}$ being non-principal.

Comment: The key point will be that non-principality lets you (in fact, forces you to) ignore finite differences. For instance, the predecessor of (the class of) the sequence $(0,1,2,...)$ will be (the class of) the sequence $(0,0,1,2,3,...)$ - the fact that the first bit of the latter is "too big" intuitively (i.e. not $-1$) doesn't matter, since that "too big"ness only happens finitely often.

Comment: Really, I'd start by trying to understand the *reduced* product $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{A}_n/\mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Frechet filter on $\mathbb{N}$ (= set of all cofinite sets of naturals). This both keeps things reasonably concrete (since $\mathcal{F}$ is much easier to describe than any nonprincipal ultrafilter) and prevents you from leaning on Los' theorem (since it doesn't apply in the first place). In particular, $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{A}_n/\mathcal{F}$ will **not** be a linear order - it will be a *partial* order, though, with many "$\mathbb{Z}$-chunks."

Comment: Note that any nonprincipal ultrapower will be a quotient of this reduced product, so they're not unrelated.

Comment: As an alternative to Noah's suggestion, you could also start by looking at the corresponding ultraproduct of the *real* intervals $[0, n]$ and the elements $f_{\alpha}(n) = \alpha n$ for $\alpha \in [0, 1]$. Observe that $f_{\alpha} < f_{\beta}$ if and only if $\alpha < \beta$. Then transfer this idea to the ultraproduct that you are interested in by using the floor function. This approach has the advantage that it easily allows you to embed any subposet of $[0, 1]$ into the ultraproduct.